# October cms User plugin many-to-many relation

Tags: many-to-many, octobercms, octobercms-user-plugin

Having the following table structure

```
user
| id | name |

class
| id | name |

users_classes
   | user_id | class_id | value |
```

I have built many to many relationship with belongsToMany
`User.php`

```
public $belongsToMany = [
        'groups' => [UserGroup::class, 'table' => 'users_groups'],
        'classes' => [UserClass::class,
            'table' => 'users_classes',
            'key'=>'user_id',
            ],
    ];
```

UserClass.php

```
public $belongsToMany = [
        'users' => [User::class,
            'table' => 'users_classes',
            'key'=>'class_id']
    ];
```

And also in rainlab\user\models\user\fields.yaml

classes:
label: class
type: relation

I can add user_id and class_id in users_classes
But I can't see VALUE field in backend form?
How can I add users_classes.value field to admin form and add some value in it?

Comment: Hey, I would suggest to watch https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LJWapm4gLkA&t=1s this tutorial offering relation is same as you wanted and still if you face any issue let me know I will add detailed answer with code

Comment: Thank you for suggestion. It was useful for me and I solved my problem

Comment: Cool , Most welcome :)